# Why can't I see the content in my custom button control template in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want all of my buttons to have a background of an image that I made.  In my app.xaml, I have the foreground of the button set to white and the background of the image is blue.  You should definitely be able to see it based on these specs.  Maybe I have done something incorrectly within my xaml.  Note that I want the appearance of the button during the hover state to be the same as the regular state.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the xaml for my buttons...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="179"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="assets/img/button.png"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Source="assets/img/button.png"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<Button Content="Submit" Margin="0,18,0,0"/>
```

All of the other settings are working.  Thanks for your time.

EDIT:  Here is my new code.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="179"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="assets/img/button.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Source="assets/img/button.png"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Doesn't your template need a `ContentPresenter`?  I'm still fairly new to WPF, especially when messing with control templates, but what you have seems off to me.  Without the `ContentPresenter` WPF doesn't know where to place the control's content within the template.

Comment: Also, I don't think you actually have to go to all the trouble of replacing the button's control template to do this.  You should just be able to define an `ImageBrush` with the `ImageSource` property set to your image, and set the `Background` property of the button directly to the `Brush`.

Comment: The `ControlTemplate` is changed, but it is filled with a `Border`and an `Image` only. So the `Button` has no reason to show anything but this.

Answer (score 2):

@BradleyUffner made all the right points to steer you in the right direction. In fact if he wanted to copy this explanation into his own answer I'd del this one and vote his up just because...

Your current example is missing pieces, and a bit of overkill. If it were me I would either add something like this to the default button template and avoid re-templating it entirely.

So for example, if you were doing it to an existing template, just replace the current `Background` property setter in the style template with something like this...

```
<Setter Property="Background">
       <Setter.Value>
          <!-- NOTE: This could be a hard set file path, a resource declaration, 
                     or could template bind it to a verbose property like `Tag` 
                     so you could supply both a default AND let them set a 
                     different image at each instance if necessary -->
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/YourImage.png"/>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

That would allow you to hit every instance of type `Button` since it's in the base style template.

You could also piggy back on the original style template like;

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="TextBox" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/YourImage.png"/>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and invoke it at the instance like;

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>
```

Or you could overwrite the entire Style template (IF you're not using `BasedOn` to grab the `ControlTemplate` etc from the default) but if you're going to do that then I would suggest starting from a default template so you don't forget things like the `ContentPresenter` and state triggers etc like Bradley pointed out.

Hope this helps, cheers.

**EDIT - CONCEPT EXAMPLE**

So say you wanted to make a button that holds content, and changes it's background image on mouseover. Well if go copy a default button template, change two things, voila and you're done. Give it a try and hope it helps clarify.

```
<!-- Used resources -->
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<!-- /END Used resources -->

<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/img/DEFAULT-BG-IMAGE.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <!-- NOTICE THIS GUY, HE PRESENTS YOUR CONTENT -->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- NOTICE THE TRIGGERS AND HOW THEY INTERACT WITH JUST PROPERTIES INSTEAD OF WHOLE TEMPLATES -->
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <!-- WE GOT MOUSEOVER? COOL, GIVE THEM A DIFFERENT PICTURE -->
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/img/MOUSEOVER-BG-IMAGE.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Button Content="Blah" Style="{DynamicResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: It feels good knowing that I'm finally starting to understand WPF.  Thank you validating what I thought was happening.

Comment: I would prefer to use the first method so the style would effect all buttons.  The problem is that the mouseover trigger doesn't effect anything when using this method.  When I add the trigger template that I had in my OP to the method you provided, the content disappears when I hover over the button.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Show me your template. I'm assuming other things probably had things in it that had other plans for the `Background` property by default and you're just running into collisions or some other inane little issue. :)

Comment: I've edited my OP to include my new code.  I've also realized that the Foreground color of the button isn't being affected either.  It's the default color of the rest of my window.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Sorry man I must not have even looked at your first attempt and not even noticed what you were doing with that MouseOver Trigger. So ya you're using the template wrong from the start. You wouldn't change the whole ControlTemplate on an event. Instead you should be interacting with properties of elements within the ControlTemplate. As it sits your new `Button` has no idea what to do with the content, and the MouseOver ControlTemplate part, well that's not going to do much for you either and goes back to the `ContentPresenter` thing mentioned before as well.

Comment: Ok, I gave your new code a try, but now i'm getting the error 'The resource "Button.Pressed.Background" could not be resolved' this happens on every line that has'Value="{StaticResource ...}"

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Ah right, so when you extract the Button template that's other stuff used as resources. I added those additional resources to the answer above the button template. You could substitute them for your own if you wanted to customize things or I'm not sure why the defaults are being found without specifically adding them like in the new example.

Comment: Ok, so i've added the new code and now I get the following error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '6'.

Line 6 is just <Application.Resources>

Comment: You copied everything in the last answer into either a resource dictionary or a `<Parent.Resources>` declaration? My stuff shouldn't cause that kind of error. I assume you have some add-in (might check add-in manager) or something. Either way, if you simply plop a default button on the design view, right click->edit template->edit a copy. You can make the same couple of changes to the default button template that your own environment is creating based on what I assume are add-in's :)